# apply function yields the wrong answer

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am trying to replace all NAs for those columns with 0 or 1 only. However, I found that apply failed to deal with the NAs. If I replace the NAs with an arbitrary string i.e. "Unknown". Then lapply and apply yield the same result. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example.

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(0,1,NA),b=c(0,1,0),c=c('d',NA,'c'))
apply(df,2,function(x){all(x %in% c(0,1,NA)) })
unlist(lapply(df,function(x){all(x %in% c(0,1,NA))}))
```

Comment: apply(df,2,function(x){all(x[!is.na(x)] %in% c(0,1,NA)) }) does not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `apply` on a `data.frame` with different classes.  The recommended option is `lapply`.  Issue is that with `apply`, it converts to `matrix` and this can result in some issues especially when there are missing values involved  i.e. creating extra spaces.

```
apply(df, 2, I)
#     a    b   c  
#[1,] " 0" "0" "d"
#[2,] " 1" "1" NA 
#[3,] NA   "0" "c"
```

If instead if the first column was already character, then the `NA` conversion from `NA_real_` to `NA_character_` wouldn't occur i.e.

```
df1 <- df
df1$a <- as.character(c(0, 1, NA))
apply(df1, 2, I)
 #    a   b   c  
#[1,] "0" "0" "d"
#[2,] "1" "1" NA 
#[3,] NA  "0" "c"
```

An option is to wrap with `trimws` to remove the `leading` spaces

```
apply(df,2,function(x){all(trimws(x) %in% c(0,1,NA)) })
#    a     b     c 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

NOTE: For testing the presence of `NA`, it is recommended to use `is.na` instead of `%in%`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!!! I wonder why trimws could make the trick?

Comment: @qwewqe213 because `trimws` function is used to remove the leading/lagging spaces and `%in%` matches on a fixed basis and there is no regex involved